# Transfer multiple selections from ListBox to Word bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a bit of a novice when it comes VBA (and coding generally) and apologize in advance if this isn't possible. I have created a userform for users to input different pieces of information (name, address, etc.). When the user clicks the "OK" command button, the values of the differing text boxes appear at various bookmarks within the Word document. For instance, TextBox 1 is dedicated to name, TextBox2 is for the address, etc.

Additionally on the userform, I have added a ListBox that lists various types of data. Ideally, I'd like to have the multiple selections from that ListBox appear at the bookmark in Word on the same line together after clicking the "OK" command button on the userform. It transfers the values to the document (where the cursor is blinking), but I can't figure out how to assign it to the bookmark.

You can see below that I'm assigning the values of the textboxes to the bookmarks and essentially want to do the same with the ListBox.

The ListBox is filled at initialization with the following code.

```
With ListBox1
.AddItem "name"  
.AddItem "address"  
.AddItem "secondary address"  
.AddItem "Social Security Number"  
.AddItem "financial account number"  
.AddItem "date of birth"  
.AddItem "email address"  
End With  

End Sub  




Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  

Dim DataSub1 As Range  
Set DataSub1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DataSub1").Range  
DataSub1 = Me.DataSub1.Value  

Dim dAddress As Range  
Set dAddress = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("dAddress").Range  
dAddress.Text = Me.dAddress.Value  

Dim ii As Integer  

        For ii = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1  
            If ListBox1.Selected(ii) Then  
                Selection.Text = ListBox1.List(ii)  
                Selection.MoveRight  
                Selection.TypeParagraph  
            End If  
        Next ii  
        Application.ScreenRefresh  

Me.Repaint  
Me.Hide  
  
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Dim ii As Integer, listText As String

For ii = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(ii) Then
        listText = listText & ListBox1.List(ii) & vbCr
    End If
Next ii
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bmkName).Range.Text = listText
```